# App gets force close when clicked on imageview in android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have a "Menu" imageview in all the pages of my app, if clicked on menu, all the menuitems like login, home, jobs, about will get open and If i click on "about" menuitem the app gets force close and getting null pointer exception on "OnClicklistener of menu" but other Menuitems are not having this issue, please can anybody solve this?

```
public class About extends Activity {
LinearLayout line1, line2;
ImageView menu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
        public void onClick(View v) {
           menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
        else { 
            line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        } 
          }
        });



          ImageView home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
          home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Home.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView jobs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jobs);
           jobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Jobs.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView log = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.log);
          log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Login.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);
          about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class));
             }
              });

}
```

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/menu" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobs"
    android:src="@drawable/about" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/jobs"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/jobs" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/log" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/home" />

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="710dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="@string/AboutPage"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/WelcometoRebuixcom"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: what does logcat say? force close usually hints that an exception has been thrown.

Comment: please post your logcat error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ImageView menu;
 menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

Look at these code lines, the Second one is cause of **Force Close**, as `menu` is **NULL**.

Just interchange it like,

```
 menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
 menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

**Update:**

You are declaring  `ImageView menu;`

Now the second line,  `menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
without defining `ImageView menu` you are setting `setOnCLickListener()` to it, which cause **NullPointerException**.

So you have to define `ImageView menu` like  `menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);`  after declaring.

Just go through for basic Android Programming and Core Java tutorial for How to declare and define Objects and Member Variables. As I think you have poor programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

you should move the code

```
ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

before

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {............
```

you should put

```
      ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

befor

```
menu.setOnClickListener
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your imageview befor onclick listener as below:

> ```
>  ImageView menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu); <<---- Here
>     menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
>         line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
>     else { 
>         line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
>     } 
>       }
>     });
> ```